# Flow3rs fDr Charlie

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, geometry, geography, three-dimensional

[image: Flow3rs fDr Charlie]

Clues: [4 contextual images]

Instructions: Name that serial killer

_ a _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution Part 1:

> The Sun Icon on the bottom left has an infinity within a clock. This points to Philadelphia, because It's ***Always Sunny in Philadelphia***. This corresponds with the title of the puzzle, because Flowers for Charlie is the name of one of the episodes.

Solution Part 2:

> The center hexagon contains a cross with repeating diagonal lines, a line bisecting two adjacent edges, and a circle bisects an edge across from the endpoint of the bisecting line. The cross points longways Northwest. 
>  
>  The cross shape is the pattern to make a cube from surfaces. (Hence the 3D in the title) 
>  
>  By drawing the pattern on a transparent sheet, folding in to a cube, and viewing it from any corner, you'll find the outline of a ***hexagon containing*** the pattern of a ***flower in a pot***. 
>  [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> cat tax
> [image]

Solution Part 2.5:

> With the location we learned from Solution 1, we can conclude that we need to align the diagram at the known location of Philadelphia. When we ***overlay the flower shape to a map*** with the sun at the center of Philadelphia, we can then orient the map according to the tilt of the cross (Northwest).

Solution Part 3:

> The icon to the farthest left looks like a pig on a mountain. When we orient the flower shape according to the cross, with the sun centered at Philadelphia, we find that the ***flower pot corresponds*** fairly closely to the ***road map***, with the right corner of the flower pot (the circle on the hexagon) centered at ***Hammonton*** (Ham Mountain).

Solution Part 4:

> [image: Ham Mountain] 
>  By rotating the map in accordance with the original orientation of the cube cutout, we can align the flower pot with the roads, Hammonton, and Philadelphia. This puts the tip of the flower "arrow" at a different location.

Comment: Very interesting! I looked at a map of the area that you mentioned and I didn't see a resemblance between the surrounding roads and the relevant shape; do you have a graphic that demonstrates the resemblance? Also, how does the instruction "name that serial killer" relate to all this?

Answer (score 3):

I have not managed to put everything together, but its been over a month and I have worked out some clues and have a guess at the answer, so will show what I have. Perhaps someone else will figure out how to put the pieces together.

---

Most of the clues are a hint towards

> The TV Show 'Its Always Sunny in Philadelphia':
>
> - 'Flowers for Charlie' is the name of S9E8 of the show
> - The sun with the infinity sign is indicating 'Always Sunny' - as further indicated by the first hint
> - The photo is of Charlie Day, who plays Charlie in the show

As hinted by the '3D' hidden in the title, the shapes

> Are 3D and represent the net of a cube and a hexagon. This is part of [Eberhard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberhard%27s_theorem), showing a hexagon can bisect a cube.
>
> And as per the hints, the picture is telling us to make the cube and view it from an angle such that the cube looks like a hexagon. When we do so, the lines form a flower pot - a reference back to the title
>
>  [image]

I have no idea for the pig however, with my best guess

> That this is hinting a phrase such as 'when pigs fly'. I have not been able to find a phrase of term that matches the picture yet.

So overall

> We know this is about the show 'Its always sunny in Philadelphia' although I'm not sure how the other parts match. Perhaps the whole picture is somehow saying the title.
>
> My best guess for an answer is based off the fact that S3E10 of the show is called 'Mac Is a Serial Killer'. The answer could therefore by 'Mac', or it could be 'Gary' who was the actual Serial Killer in the episode.
>
> It could also be 'Gary Heidnik' or 'Harrison Graham' - serial killers from Philadelphia.
>
> None of these guesses quite fit the enumeration of the answer, but all have 'A' as their second letter.

---

This is the best I've managed to put together, perhaps someone else can get some more insight into the problem...

Comment: Nice work so far! I added another hint for you. :)

Comment: The TV episode that the question references is itself a reference to a novel. I don't know whether or not that fact has any significance.

Comment: @Tyler ah that makes more sense - and very cool! However still not sure how at all how that works for the puzzle... will add it in for now